# How to use mysql join to deal with duplicate insertion when there is no primary key - MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have a table which looks like following

```
CREATE TABLE `groups` (
`id_rec` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`id_group` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
UNIQUE INDEX `unikum` (`id_rec`, `id_group`),
INDEX `idxgroup` (`id_group`))
```

there is no primary key like id of the table on which i can use insert on duplicate key clause. Now i am trying to insert multiple rows with signle MySQL query in groups table, but i don't want insert duplicates. Now, the solution i came up with is creating and inserting in another temporary table and then use join on group table and temporary table in order to find duplicates or non-duplicates(new) records depending on the join that i should use.

The temporary table looks like following

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tempTable
(id INT(11) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
 group_id INT(11) NOT NULL, 
 id_rec INT(11) NOT NULL)
```

Now at this point i am not sure which join should i use. Any help would be grealty appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a primary key for `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to work. The unique index you have is perfectly fine.

You can alternatively use `INSERT IGNORE`:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `groups` VALUES (1, 1);
```

If the pair `(1, 1)` already exists in your table then the above statement will be simply ignored.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7daa9/1)

Comment: Great!! this looks promising, but a quick question. Would this work with multiple records like INSERT IGNORE INTO `groups` VALUES (1, 1), (1,2), (1, 3);?

Comment: @Shaonline In that case the duplicate values will be skipped and the rest inserted. Look [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/31d2f/1) for a demo.

Comment: can you take a look at this please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35943395/how-to-perform-batch-operation-using-mysql-and-php