# How to perform batch operation using mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, loops, batch-processing

I am trying to insert multiple records using single MySQL query, but i don't want to insert a huge number of records at once.

The following code fetches, buildes and inserts the records

```
if(is_array($id_rec)){
        $values = "";
        foreach($id_rec as $key=>$value){
            $values .= "(".(int)$value.",".(int)$id_group."), ";
        }
        $values = rtrim($values,", ");
        $sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO fu_rec_group_link (id_rec, id_group) VALUES ".$values;
        $GLOBALS['db']->execute($sql);
```

I have two questions here.

1. Frist Question:
   How many records should i insert at once? What is right amount?
2. Second Question:
   How can i pause/break the loop after reaching the max limit of records and insert it and then continue from i left?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Limits depends on your server. Ask you provider about that. To continue operation after period of time - try `sleep()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php

Comment: If you can run your script by commandline, this is a typical commanline-job. Otherwise, you can use ajax to perform step-by-step queries

Comment: @Qrzysio I am talking about limit of records to insert at once not time limit. I don't think you understand what i am trying to explain, may be i didn't explain well. But i am trying to insert 1000 records at once and continue with the rest of records with another insert query if the records are more than 1000 for example.

Comment: I clearly understand. Putting records slower may let you to avoid server limits as they are usually base on time-execution.
1000 records it's not a lot in fact. I don't know which hosting you use and what the limit there are, but 1000 records shouldn't overload your sever at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should insert as many records as possible in a single INSERT as opposed to breaking it down into many INSERTS.

For example, doing

```
INSERT INTO mytable (column1, column2, column3)
VALUES ('text', 'text', 'text'),
       ('text', 'text', 'text'),
       ('text', 'text', 'text'),
       ('text', 'text', 'text');
```

is faster than doing

```
INSERT INTO mytable (column1, column2, column3)
VALUES ('text', 'text', 'text'),
       ('text', 'text', 'text');
INSERT INTO mytable (column1, column2, column3)
VALUES ('text', 'text', 'text'),
       ('text', 'text', 'text');
```

The aggregate difference in performance is more pronounced as the number of rows go up.

Comment: even if there are like i don't know 100,000 records?

Comment: @Shaonline If there's no pause between your multiple INSERTS, you are better off doing them in a single INSERT